# How to read Json data sent with HttpPost from android to Rest web service

Tags: android, web-services, http, rest

I'm new to web service development, and I'm a bit lost at this particular step.
i am sending JSON data from Android phone (it's simply text I enter in two EditTexts, and I need to recuperate in my java app ) to Restful web service and want to get that Data and search for it in database.

In Android, I used a simple httpPost to send the information.

This is my android code :

```
    Map<String, String> comment = new HashMap<String, String>();    
    comment.put(login.getText().toString(),"Using the GSON library");
    comment.put(pswd.getText().toString(),"Using libraries is convenient.");                    
    String json = new GsonBuilder().create().toJson(comment,Map.class);                     
    makeRequest("http://10.0.2.2:8080/com.WebService/rest/hello",json);
```

then, the http post

```
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(uri);
    httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(json));
    httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    return new DefaultHttpClient().execute(httpPost);
```

My question is : what should I do in my java web service to receive this data, and do with it whatever I want later. (I'm confused between @Post and @Put, and I'm not even sure if that's what I really need)

Comment: What should you do in the webservice? You should listen to requests and handle them accordingly.. your question is a bit vague..

Comment: In my web service, I should receive the text sent from my android, and make a search method to see weather this data exists in my Database or not.